# What is the H2 default jdbc url in micronaut

Tags: jdbc, h2, micronaut

I have following datasource configuration in application.yml (Micronaut defaults):

```yaml
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: 'user'
    password: 'user'
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: H2
jpa.default.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

Hikari logs following:

```
21:09:01.750 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Which seems to be correct. I attempt to connect to the database, and succeed. Hovever `SHOW TABLES` returns nothing. When I add `IFEXISTS=true` to url, I get the following error:

```
[90146][90146] Database "mem:devDb" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it [90146-200].
```

The application is working - I can insert and fetch data, but I don't have a clue where the data is located, and how to access it outside the app.

Comment: This is an H2 `mem` database - an [in-memory DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases). The documentation explains the location and access restrictions for such databases. Basically, it exists only inside the JVM running your app. There is no external storage location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the H2 default jdbc url in micronaut

For the `hibernate-jpa` feature the default url is `jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`.

> ...but I don't have a clue where the data is located, and how to access
> it outside the app.

The data is located in memory, only accessible by the application that created the in memory database.  If you want any other process to access the data, your app that is using the in memory database would need to provide access to the data (like through an API, for example).

This is only a limitation because you are using an in memory database.  Using an in memory database may not be the best solution for you if you need multiple processes connecting to the database.

Comment: I had hoped, that it would expose itself on some port - with a bit of configuration perhaps.